# Common tokens for flex and bison

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

I have one file with declarations of my tokens declarations.h:

```
#define ID 257
#define NUM 258
...
```

In my flex code i return one of this values or symbol(for example '+', '-', '*'). And everything works.

The problem in bison file.
If i write something like that:
exp: ID '+' ID
i'll get error, because bison doesn't know anything about ID. 
Adding the line %token ID will not help, because in that case i'll have compilation error(preprocessor will change ID by 257 and i'll get 257=257)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get Bison to create the list of tokens; your lexer uses the list generated by Bison.

```
bison -d grammar.y
# Generates grammar.tab.c and grammar.tab.h
```

Your lexer then uses `grammar.tab.h`:

```
$ cat grammar.y
%token ID
%%
program:    /* Nothing */
    |       program ID
    ;
%%
$ cat lexer.l
%{
#include "grammar.tab.h"
%}
%%
[a-zA-Z][A-Za-z_0-9]+   { return ID; }
[ \t\n]                 { /* Nothing */ }
.                       { return *yytext; }
%%
$ bison -d grammar.y
$ flex lexer.l
$ gcc -o testgrammar grammar.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -lfl
$ ./testgrammar
id est
quod erat demonstrandum
$
```

Bison 2.4.3 on MacOS X 10.7.2 generates the token numbers as an `enum`, not as a series of `#define` values - to get the token names into the symbol table for debuggers (a very good idea!).